# ADF Copy Actitity issue

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I have an issue where I can preview data from a source, a SQL Server connected through a Self-Hosted IR, but I cannot copy the data to a sink (Azure SQL DB on an EP).

The user account at the SQL Server level has access to the relevant tables, as can be verified by the fact that I can preview data. The sink side dataset also works, as I can use with similar data sources to the source.

If I, for example, try to fetch two specific rows, I can see them in the preview, but it takes 5 minutes for ADF to give an error message which is wildly misleading:

> ErrorCode=SqlFailedToConnect,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Cannot connect to SQL Database: 'ServerName.database.windows.net', Database: 'DatabaseName', User: 'AdminUserName'. Check the linked service configuration is correct, and make sure the SQL Database firewall allows the integration runtime to access.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.),Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=10060,Class=20,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=0,Errors=[{Class=20,Number=10060,State=0,Message=A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.),},],''Type=System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception,Message=A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond,Source=,'

What am I doing wrong? Is there some setting I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether the Azure SQL DB(sink) is accessible from the server on which you have installed the self hosted IR.
YOu would need to whitelist the IP of the Self IR server in Azure SQL DB firewall rules and make some port opening in the IR server for Auzre SQL DB to be accessible.
Basically in case if an IR is being used in a copy activity, both the source and sink must be accessible from the server on which IR is set up

Comment: Thanks for this. It turned out my client had a faulty NAT setting, which were blocking everything.

Comment: Glad I could help :) Can you please upvote and accept it as answer as it might benefit other community members as well